# Why 'ng e2e' command does not work truly?

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor

I try to run 'ng e2e' on this project

[automate-end-to-end-e2e-testing-for-angular-7-using-protractor-jasmine](https://medium.com/@dhormale/automate-end-to-end-e2e-testing-for-angular-7-using-protractor-jasmine-4ce171aaeedc)

but this command does not following thing:

1- Run spec in browser (default browser configured is chrome which run with message ‘Chrome is being controlled by automated test software’)

2- Log test execution result on console as below.

termainl show this:

[image: terminal message]

and intellij IDEA shows on top of app.e2e-spec.ts page this message:

[image: TSLint:FetalError:Failed to load]

what's wrong?

Comment: Run `npm install codelyzer`

Comment: @SaddamPojee The package is installed with some warnings but e2e testing does not work after it.

Comment: Can you post what written in `Details` section of the error?

Comment: I resolved this problem with using vpn.

Answer (score 0):

I checked by running the code. It's pretty clear that `protractor.conf.js` file is missing in `e2e` folder.

That file is needed, as you have reference to the file in `angular.json` file at [Line 113](https://github.com/dhormale/e2e-testing-Angular-Protractor-Jasmine/blob/10041a66f2ebc48bf8a872b6a48f0b91e6a94bd0/angular.json#L113).

`protractor.conf.js` is responsible for providing config to Protractor for e2e testing. Typically, it looks like below:

```js
// Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json')
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```